# Cannot read input file in the program to read QR Code

Tags: java, qr-code

I'm trying to make the program to read QR codes, however when my code runs I am getting an exception `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file`. The image is in the *src* directory. Could someone please help me to find the problem in my code...

```
public class BarcodeSample {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/img.png"));
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

            Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

            BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat();
            String text = result.getText();

            ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
            for (int i=0; i < points.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("    Point[" + i + "] = " + points[i]);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `File.separator` instead of `'/'` as it places the right separator according to the OS it is running on.

Now the problem is with `src/img.png`. I suggest you put your images outside the `src` directory as this directory is used for code (not a must).

I do not know on which IDE you run it but make sure your workspace current directory is set to your project root directory so `src/img.png` will be found (assuming `src` is under you root current directory), otherwise you will get the file not found exception

Comment: Finally, I could solve the problem.

(1)I put my image outside the src directory. 
(2)At the beginning, I made a large size QR code and tried to read it. But could not. 
Then I replaced it with a small size QR ode and could read. But I do not know why.

Thank you very much for your help!